# Vue onclick display specific item

Tags: vuejs2

I have a question about Vue.

I want to add a class to a specific item:

```
<p v-on:click="display = !display">Rediger joke</p>
```

Display is False before and it change it to true.

And it works. But my problem is, that this onclick is inside an v-for loop, and i only want to put "display" on one "update-site" and not all of them. Can i do this or do I have to try a different setup?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the use of `Display` and how do you identify one item inside for loop? Add a minimal, but full demo code so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this idea that might help you. The idea is you extend `post` object with for example `visible` property and when you `click event` triggered you change this property and add `.display` class. Please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j48knaz0/1/)

template

```
 <div id="app">
   <article v-for="post in filteredPosts" :key="post.id">
     {{post.name}}
     <button @click="display(post)">show</button>
     <div class="post-content" :class="{display: post.visible}">this is the part I want to display onclick</div>
     <hr />
   </article>
 </div>
```

css

```
.post-content {
  display: none;
}

.post-content.display {
  display: block;
}
```

code

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    //when you load posts. add visible property.
    setTimeout(() => {
      //posts from server
      var postsFromServer = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Post One'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Post Two'
        }
      ];

      //add visible proprty.
      this.posts = postsFromServer.map(post => {
        return {
          ...post,
          visible: false
        };
      });
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      //do your filters
      return this.posts;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    display(post) {
      this.$set(post, 'visible', !post.visible);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an article, and i get the data from Firebase.

```
<article v-for="post in filteredPosts" :key="post.id">
{{post.name}}
<p v-on:click="display = !display"></p>
<div>this is the part I want to display onclick</div
</article>
```

updateInputs has display:none, but onclick I want it to be display as block:

```
.updateInputs.display {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      bottom: 0;
     background-color: white;
     box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```